# How to pass the clientId the user is authenticating with using a custom AuthenticationProvider in Spring Authorization Server?

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I am using Spring Authorization Server and implementing a custom `AuthenticationProvider` such as following when a user logs-in:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationCallout implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationCallout.class);

    @Autowired
    private JpaOAuth2AuthorizationService jpaOAuth2AuthorizationService;

    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    public AuthenticationCallout(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        LOG.info("authenticate with username and password");

        final String name = authentication.getName();
        final String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();


        LOG.info("authorities: {}, details: {}, credentials: {}", authentication.getAuthorities(),
                authentication.getDetails(), authentication.getCredentials());

        if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("system")) {
            final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            final UserDetails principal = new User(name, password, grantedAuths);
            LOG.info("returning using custom authenticator");
            final Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password, grantedAuths);
            return auth;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I also want to get the clientId with which this user is logging-in with.  What is the best way to get the clientId?  In this custom authentication I will be making a webclient call to another service that stores the user-password with the clientId for the system.

Comment: I think you actually want to be implementing [`UserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/user-details-service.html#servlet-authentication-userdetailsservice) with [`DaoAuthenticationProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/dao-authentication-provider.html#servlet-authentication-daoauthenticationprovider) for this use case, covered in the [Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/index.html) chapter of Spring Security's reference.

Comment: I just don't see a way to get the clientId though when user logs in.  Is there a way to access that?

Comment: I'm assuming you're working towards a multi-tenant solution? Are you simply trying to access the `client_id` (query parameter) that was sent by the OAuth2 client in the redirect to the authorization server?

Comment: Yes, multi-tenant.  I want to send the username/password + clientId to another authentication provider that is accessible thru another microservice called authentication-rest-service.  That authentication-rest-service will send back some custom roles for a given  clientId and loginId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are potentially quite a few ways to tackle this. For example, adding your own `Filter` to the Spring Security filter chain gives you direct access to the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`. However, you can also access this through Spring's `RequestContextHolder` in a non-filter component.

The simplest way to start would be to implement the `UserDetailsService` and access the `SavedRequest` used to initiate the flow via the `RequestCache`, like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    // ...

    @Bean
    public RequestCache requestCache() {
        return new HttpSessionRequestCache();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(RequestCache requestCache) {
        return (username) -> {
            var clientId = getClientId(requestCache);
            // ...
        };
    }

    private static String getClientId(RequestCache requestCache) {
        var requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        var request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
        var response = requestAttributes.getResponse();
        var savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
        return getParameter(savedRequest, OAuth2ParameterNames.CLIENT_ID);
    }

    private static String getParameter(SavedRequest savedRequest, String parameterName) {
        var parameterValues = savedRequest.getParameterValues(parameterName);
        if (parameterValues.length != 1) {
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_REQUEST);
        }
        return parameterValues[0];
    }

}
```

The [`UserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/user-details-service.html#servlet-authentication-userdetailsservice) can then look up the user from the external service. This requires the hashed password to be part of the response from the microservice, so the password can be validated locally by the [`DaoAuthenticationProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/dao-authentication-provider.html#servlet-authentication-daoauthenticationprovider).

Comment: The requestCache helped with the UserDetailsService  lambda expression. However, I was wondering if that clientId was encapsulated  in the `authentication` object in my `AuthenticationProvider` implementation.

Comment: Sorry @Katlock, I'm not sure I follow. It looks like your `AuthenticationProvider` snippet is not complete. The provider requires a specific `Authentication` instance type, which is passed by a specific filter in the filter chain. Nothing would know to pass your `clientId` through an `authentication` unless you customized more of the filter chain. In addition, the `client_id` parameter is not on the request when authentication happens because you are redirected to a login page. You need to "remember" the `clientId` somehow, or pass it forward, all of which requires customization.

Comment: I am using AuthenticationProvider implementation in this case as the username/password is not on the authorization-server system but rather needs to be sent to another system for validation.  I will check out the filters later but for now the request cache helped.