# Password Reset Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring, spring-authorization-server, authorization-server

I implemented the password reset flow in the spring authorization
server with an email token. The implementation is similar to the
[OWASP Forgot Password](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet.html)
The problem is that I do not know how to get the registered client when clicking the reset password link on the login form. It is possible to call this reset password URL without the client, and this shouldn't be possible.

When I open this URL in the browser, I get redirected to the login form.

```
http://localhost:8083/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code &client_id=client
   &scope=openid
   &redirect_uri=http://example.com
   &code_challenge=MyChallengeCode
   &code_challenge_method=S256
```

Login Form: [image]

When I click the reset password link, the flow starts.
[image]

My Questions:

- How can I get the client credentials for my reset password view?
- Should I implement it with my own  OAuth2 Authorization Endpoint?
- How can I add the client to reset password link on the login page?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question "How can I get the client credentials for my reset password view?" It seems you're conflating some concepts together when trying to build this flow. For the purposes of "self-service" pages, you should not be using OAuth2 as the authorization server is really just a regular secured application (e.g. the auth server is not a client of itself).

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg what I mean is when I navigate to my SPA I call the auth service with a client. e.g. authorize?response_type=code &client_id=client...
Then I get redirected to the login page. But now I want to reset my password and now I lose the client information. I thought it must be something like this: /reset-password?client_id=aa1fdc93-08...

Comment: You can't use a SPA that is an OAuth2 client to make protected requests to the authorization server as an anonymous user. The authorization server should have its own UI (probably not a SPA) for login **and** self-service password reset. Perhaps I still don't understand the question.

Comment: Ok lets try this: I want to check if the registered client is able to reset the password or not. When i get redirected to the login page how can i receive and validate the credentials when i click on Reset Password.

Comment: "I want to check if the registered client is able to reset the password or not."  The user (and password) does not belong to a registered client. The password belongs to the user, and the user logs into the authorization server in order to authorize a client. Therefore the authorization server owns the user (identity/record). "When i get redirected to the login page how can i receive and validate the credentials when i click on Reset Password." No credentials have been exchanged yet. So again the question doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Perhaps what you're asking is "How do I get the client_id query parameter from the authorization request in the password reset flow?"??

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg yes this is what i mean. Not only the client id but all parameters. Sorry for my bad explanation

Answer (score 0):

The question is not 100% clear on your goal but based on clarifying questions in comments, it seems you are trying to access to query parameters that were submitted with the authorization request. Using your example:

```
http://localhost:8083/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code &client_id=client
   &scope=openid
   &redirect_uri=http://example.com
   &code_challenge=MyChallengeCode
   &code_challenge_method=S256
```

Let's say we want to access the `client_id` parameter during the Forgot Password flow. The easiest way to accomplish this would be to use the `RequestCache`, since this is what stores the original URL in order to replay the request after the user authenticates successfully. Here is a simplified example:

```java
@Controller
public class ForgotPasswordController {

    private final RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

    @GetMapping("/password/forgot")
    public String forgot(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        var savedRequest = this.requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
        var clientId = savedRequest.getParameterValues("client_id")[0];
        // ...
    }

}
```

See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76282653/15835039) for an additional example.

Comment: thank u very much i will try it. Maybe you can take a look to this link too: [sid_missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77093539/sid-missing-in-id-token-using-spring-authorization-server/77224662?noredirect=1#comment136144759_77224662)

Comment: @nucle If this answer helped you, please consider upvoting it. Thanks. Also, I added a comment to your answer. Please open a new question with a minimal reproducer to help diagnose your issue.